# I am using websockify 0.8.0 the latest version, but it doesn't support TLS-1.2

Tags: tls1.2, websockify, novnc

I am using websockify 0.8.0 the latest version, but it doesn't support TLS-1.2 by default. I am looking for the strong cipher to be displayed for **sslscan --no-hearbleed hostname:6080** command output.

***Adding some extra info to make the question more clear :*** On running the below command, 3DES cipher is resulted with the least strength i.e. **C**.

**nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 6080 hostname**

On the same host DES is disabled for port 443. So it seems for nginx it has been taken care but for python-websockify it is still present.

So in brief I am finding the way to disable the 3DES cipher on port 6080 of the host. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. **https://notes.bitfunnel.net/?q=node/54** helped.